# Jquery autocomplete and output on same page script

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need jquery help. And I'm an extreme nube.

What I want is several input fields (say, 1-5) each with autocomplete. If I find my desired input, I select it from the offer. If not what I write is added to the list on that given field (1 has it's own list, 2 it's own etc).

The lists should be saved in a DB on the server so the next person sees any additions.

The output should appear on the same page as it's selected / written in the fields.

Basically, I want a sentence builder (input 1 is subject, 2 is verb, 3 is object, etc). In the future I'd like to be able to make it into a slang translation engine with crowd verification and "Vulgarity Rating". But right now I'm just looking for a prototype of the input.

Anyone want to help or point me toward where I can find info to do it myself?

Comment: Could you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Elaborate more with an example if possible.